# Not getting data from req.body

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mern

I have been trying to update product on my ecommerce website, when update button is clicked no errors are showing, its showing the old data and no change in the mongodb database.

when i print "req.body.name" in the controller code, it shows undefined in the console.

somebody please suggest a change in the code

Controller

```
import Product from "../models/productModel.js";
import Category from "../models/categoryModel.js"
import multer from "multer";
import productModel from "../models/productModel.js";
export const updateproducts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("name "+req.body.name)
        const product = await productModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                
                name: req.body.name,
                description: req.body.description,
                images: req.body.images,
                mrp: req.body.mrp,
                category: req.body.category,
                InStock: req.body.InStock,
                rating: req.body.rating,
                numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
                isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured
            },
            { new: true }
        );

        if (!product) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Product not found or cannot be updated.' });
        }

        res.json({ message: 'Product updated successfully', updatedProduct: product });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
};
```

frontend

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AdminSidebar from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminSidebar'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import axios from "axios";
import { faTrashCan } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import AdminHeader from '../../components/Layout/admin/adminheader'
import "./Admindashboard.css"


const UpdateProduct = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [mrp, setMrp] = useState("");
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const params = useParams();
  const [InStock, setInStock] = useState("");
  const [selectedImages, setSelectedImages] = useState([]);
  const [pid, setId] = useState("");
  const [DeletedImages,setDeletedImages] = useState([])


  const getSingleProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/getsingle-product/${params.id}`);
      console.log(data)

      setName(data.product.name);
      setId(data.product._id);
      setDescription(data.product.description);
      setSelectedImages(data.product.images);
      setMrp(data.product.mrp);
      setCategory(data.product.category);
      setInStock(data.product.InStock);
      if (data.success) {
        console.log("hai")
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something wwent wrong in getting catgeory");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getSingleProduct(params.id);
    console.log(params.id)
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  const getAllCategory = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/category/get-category");
      if (data.success) {
        setCategories(data.category);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Something wwent wrong in getting catgeory");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCategory();
  }, []);


  //update product function
  const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    try {

      const productData = new FormData();
      productData.append("name", name);
      productData.append("description", description);
      for (let img of selectedImages) {
        productData.append("images", img);
      }

      productData.append("mrp", mrp);
      productData.append("category", category);
      productData.append("InStock", InStock);

      const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/product/update-product/${params.id}`, {productData});
      console.log(productData)
        
      if (data?.success) {
        toast.error(data?.message);
      } else {
        toast.success("Product Created Successfully");
        navigate("/dashboard/manage.vision/admin/products");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("something went wrong");
    }
  };

  const onSelectFile = (event) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    const selectedFilesArray = Array.from(selectedFiles);
    
  
    setSelectedImages((previousImages) => previousImages.concat(selectedFilesArray));
    console.log(selectedImages)
  
    // FOR BUG IN CHROME
    event.target.value = "";
  };
  
  const deleteHandler = (file) => {

    setDeletedImages((prevDeletedImages) => [...prevDeletedImages, file]);

    const remainingImages = selectedImages.filter((f) => f !== file);
    setSelectedImages(remainingImages);
  };

  

  return (
    <body className='body'>
      <div className="container-fluid ">
        <div className="row">
          <AdminHeader />

          <AdminSidebar />

          <div className="col-md-3">
            <div>
              <button>Cancel</button><button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
              <div className="prgrid">
                <div className='upimg'>
                  <h4 className="prhead">Product Images<hr></hr>
                  </h4>
                  <div >
                    <input type="file" id='upload' accept="image/png, image/jpeg,image/webp" onChange={onSelectFile} multiple >

                    </input><label className="label" for="upload"><h3 >Upload +</h3></label>
                    <div className="images">
                      {selectedImages &&
                        selectedImages.map((image, index) => {
                          return (
                            <div key={image} className="image">
                              <img src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/${image}`} alt="upload" className="primg" />
                              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className="prdele" onClick={() => deleteHandler(image)} />
                              <p className="imgno">{index + 1}</p>
                            </div>
                          );
                        })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="prcat">
                  <h4 className="prhead">Product Catagory</h4><hr></hr>

                  <Form.Select className="catsel" onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)
                  }>{categories?.map((c) => (
                    <option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                      {c.name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                  </Form.Select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="prinfo">
                <h4 className="prhead">Product Info</h4><hr></hr>

                <Form.Label htmlFor="prname" className="prlab">Name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  id="prname"
                  value={name}
                  placeholder="Product Name"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <Form.Group
                  className="mb-3"
                  controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1"
                >
                  <Form.Label className="prlab">Description</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} className="prdes" value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Group>
              </div>
              <div className="prprice">
                <h4 className="prhead">Product Pricing</h4><hr></hr>
                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Maximum Retail Price</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="number"
                  id="prpice"
                  value={mrp}
                  onChange={(e) => setMrp(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="prprice">
                <h4 className="prhead">Inventory Status</h4><hr></hr>
                <Form.Label htmlFor="prpice" className="prlab">Status</Form.Label>
                <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example" className="stat" value={InStock} onChange={(e) => setInStock(e.target.value)}>
                  <option >Update Status</option>
                  <option value="0">In Stock</option>
                  <option value="1">Out Of Stock</option>
                </Form.Select></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  )
}


export default UpdateProduct
```

Comment: You need to have a body parser middleware. If you are using expressjs, you can refer to this: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser.

Comment: but i have created catagory update for my project it worked without body parser
i think body parser is inbuild in express

Answer (score 0):

You're not using correct request format with axios, meaning that instead of a form and multipart type request, you're actually sending a JSON object here:

```
const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/product/update-product/${params.id}`, {productData});
```

Try changing it to this (omit `{}`):

```
const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/v1/product/update-product/${params.id}`, productData);
```

docs: [Multipart Bodies](https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart)

Also, make sure you have multer middleware on that route, processing an array of files in `images` field, it should look something like this:

```
app.put('/api/v1/product/update-product/:id', upload.array('images', 10), updateproducts);
```

docs: [Usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#usage)

and images will be in `req.files`, not `req.body.images`, see the examples in the above link to multer docs.